# load cell Arduino HX711 library not Starting

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to build a scale set up with a 20kg load cell to test the power of rocket engines. I am using these steps to build it and when I run the balances program it gives me this error. Yes, I have Installed the library.

```
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'HX711::HX711(int, int)'
```

And here is the code

```
 /* Calibration sketch for HX711 */

#include "HX711.h"  // Library needed to communicate with HX711 https://github.com/bogde/HX711

#define DOUT  6  // Arduino pin 6 connect to HX711 DOUT
#define CLK  5  //  Arduino pin 5 connect to HX711 CLK

HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);  // Init of library

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  scale.set_scale();  // Start scale
  scale.tare();       // Reset scale to zero
}

void loop() {
  float current_weight=scale.get_units(20);  // get average of 20 scale readings
  float scale_factor=(current_weight/0.145);  // divide the result by a known weight
  Serial.println(scale_factor);  // Print the scale factor to use
}
```

Would love some help and here is the link to the web site  https://www.brainy-bits.com/load-cell-and-hx711-with-arduino/

Comment: Where is `HX711.cpp` located?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);` with `HX711 scale;` then add `scale.begin(DOUT, CLK);` at beginning of the void setup()

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make an object `scale` of HX711 and then call `scale.begin(DOUT, CLK)` in setup function.

Try to change your code like this

```
#include "HX711.h"  // Library needed to communicate with HX711 https://github.com/bogde/HX711

#define DOUT  6  // Arduino pin 6 connect to HX711 DOUT
#define CLK  5  //  Arduino pin 5 connect to HX711 CLK

HX711 scale;  // Init of library

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  scale.begin(DOUT, CLK);  // Start scale
  scale.tare();       // Reset scale to zero
}
```